# C programming with Eclipse (library mystery)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, shared-libraries

When I connect a library to my program, Eclipse doesn't generate any executable file, I get only an object file.
When I disconnect the library from my program (delete all paths and library functions), I get an executable.

However, I don't get any error in the first case.

What is going wrong?

I work with: Linux, C, Eclipse.

Log:

**** Build of configuration Debug for project Wise_test_C ****

```
make all 
Building target: Wise_test_C
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -L"/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug" -o"Wise_test_C"  ./src/Wise_test_C.o   -lWISE_C
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvGetRawData'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvPow'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvCreateGraphScanner'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvColorToScalar'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `Fuzzy10'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvExp'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvTransform'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvAddS'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvHoughLines2'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvSetAdd'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvAvgSdv'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvError'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvSeqSlice'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `floor'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvCircle'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvGetCols'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvAlloc'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvRead'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvFitLine'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvUndistort2'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvLog'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvFree_'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvCalcEMD2'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvGetElemType'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvPolyLine'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvFitEllipse2'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvBoundingRect'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvPerspectiveTransform'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvCalcArrHist'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvCalibrateCamera2'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `Fuzzy24'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvInvert'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvAvg'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvSum'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvProjectPoints2'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvSet'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvRandArr'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvReshape'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvGetSeqElem'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvBoxPoints'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvSetImageROI'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvMinAreaRect2'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvInitSubdivDelaunay2D'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvFindFundamentalMat'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvSet2D'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvLine'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvReleaseGraphScanner'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvRodrigues2'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvKMeans2'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvEllipse'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvInitFont'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvResetImageROI'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvGet2D'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvFindChessboardCorners'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvGetFileNodeByName'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvSplit'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvCartToPolar'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvGetRows'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvCreateSubdiv2D'
/export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/libWISE_C.so: undefined reference to `cvConvexHull2'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Wise_test_C] Fehler 1
```

Comment: You'll need to post the build log for us to help you

Comment: Where I can find log file? Does eclipse generate any?

Comment: @lerax ... thanks for the build output. See my edit .. seems like OpenCV isn't being linked :)

Answer (score 4):

Look in the logs / build output. The linker can't find the library you mean so compilation stops at object generation.

**edit** with respect to:

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The linker is failing

**My guess ... OpenCV isn't being linked**
It looks like your program also uses **OpenCV**. You need to link your executable to openCV so that the symbols in the library libWISE_C.so are resolved. Either add the dependency through eclipse or do it manually. Remember you need to include the opencv headers, include the library path through "-L" and also link the library binary.

In Eclipse, right-click on your project and go to Properties. Next, open the Libraries section under GCC C++ Linker. In the Libraries (-l) panel add an entry with the value for opencv and click OK.

**Good LucK**

Comment: But I have linked OpenCV in my library and I don't use anything from OpenCV in my program. Is it not enough? Do I need to link both libraries in me program if only libWISE_C.so need OpenCV?

Comment: If you open a terminal and type `ldd libWISE_C.so` in /export/home/pdmazubi3/workspace/WISE_C/Debug/ does opencv show up in the list?

Comment: Bottom line is opencv isn't being included by your library or program hence the ld error. Use ldd to obtain output on each.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `libWISE_C.so` is using [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) or a similar library. You *must* provide that other library on the link line for the executable, or you will not get a successful link.

Since you built `libWISE_C.so` yourself, you should know which other library all the undefined symbols are supposed to come from.

You may also be able to add this "other library" to the link line of `libWISE_C.so` itself, and thus free `libWISE_C.so` clients from the need to do so.

Comment: Hi, I wrote libWISE_C.so myself. I just want to test it.